# PHP Laravel foreach to iterate json data from api

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, foreach

So I am very new to PHP and Laravel and having a tough time trying to do a foreach loop in order to grab 'number' and 'step' inside 'analyzedInstructions' array. I was able to get the 'title', 'readyInMinutes' and 'instruction' but cannot get anything within 'analyzedInstructions'.

Here's the dd of the json:

```
{#203 ▼
  +"id": 602534
  +"title": "Bok Choy with Ground Chicken Stir Fry"
  +"readyInMinutes": 15
  +"image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/Bok-Choy-with-Ground-Chicken-Stir-Fry-602534.jpg"
  +"instructions": "In a wok or large saute pan over high heat, add the cooking oil. When hot, add ground chicken and saute until browned (but not fully cooked through). Lower heat ▶"
  +"analyzedInstructions": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#558 ▼
      +"name": ""
      +"steps": array:4 [▼
        0 => {#559 ▼
          +"number": 1
          +"step": "In a wok or large saute pan over high heat, add the cooking oil. When hot, add ground chicken and saute until browned (but not fully cooked through). Lower heat ▶"
          +"ingredients": array:5 [▶]
          +"equipment": array:2 [▶]
        }
        1 => {#567 ▶}
        2 => {#573 ▶}
        3 => {#576 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My Controller with my api/key:

```
    public function selectedrecipe($id){
        $response = Unirest::get("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.mashape.com/recipes/" . $id . "/information?includeNutrition=true",
            array(
                "X-Mashape-Key" => " KEY ",
                "Accept" => "application/json"
            )
        );

        return view('search.show')->withSelected($response->body);
    }
```

I'm trying to loop through to get 'number' and 'step' insides of 'steps' and have them listed in my blade.

Show blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>{{ $selected->title }}</h1>
        <div id="recipeInfo">
            <img class="recipeImg" src="{{ $selected->image }}"/>
                <div class="recipeText">
                    <h2>Instructions</h2>
                    <p>Total Time: {{ $selected->readyInMinutes }} minutes</p>
                    <p>{{ $selected->instructions }}</p>

                    {{$selected->sourceUrl}}

                    @foreach($selected->analyzedInstructions[0]->steps[0]->number as $select)
                        {{$select}}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
        </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: That should probably be `@foreach($selected->analyzedInstructions[0]->steps as $step)` and then `{{ $step->number }}` or similar.

Comment: @JoelHinz Yes, got it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting specific indices of your arrays instead of iterating over them, this will cause you to only print one result.

```
@foreach($selected->analyzedInstructions as $instruction)
  <p>Steps:</p>
  @foreach($instruction->steps as $step}}
    <p>Numbers:</p>
    @foreach($ste[->number as $select)
      {{$select}}
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This will instead iterate over every element in the array and their childs.